# Variables in an if condition in a pipeline's variables section

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a template with common variables defined for my pipelines, it contains a variable that tell whether if it's a main branch among other things.

the code in said template looks something like this:

```
myVars:
  - name: dev_registry
    value: azurethis.io
  - name: prod_registry
    value: azurethat.io
  - name: isMaster
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')]
```

now in my pipeline, I have a template that consumes a `registry` variable, and I wanted to send this variable depending on the `isMaster` variable from the template.

This is how the variables look on my pipeline:

```
variables: 
  - template: myVars.yaml
  - name: registry
    ${{ if eq(myVars.isMaster, 'true') }}:
      value: $(myVars.prod_registry)
    ${{ else }}:
      value: $(myVars.dev_registry)
  - name: someKey
    ${{ if eq(myVars.isMaster, 'true') }}:
      value: $(LIBRARY_KEY_PROD)
    ${{ else }}:
      value: $(LIBRARY_KEY_DEV)
```

Later in the pipeline, I consume it as follows:

```
jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      steps:
        - template: extras/deploy-thingz.template.yaml
          parameters:
            registry: $(registry)
            ...
```

This is not working and I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Unrecognized value: 'if'
```

My questions now are:

1- is it even allowed to use if conditions in the variables section of a pipeline and if yes, where is my syntax error?

2- Can I set a variable's value using variables within the same variables section of the pipeline?

Comment: So a suggestion here is to review how you are scoping and using your variables.  Variables can be scoped at the job, stage, and pipeline level. If these values not secrets I'd recommend moving these variables to a separate variable. yml file. The check can then choose which variable files to load in the appropriate scope. This will allow you to scale easier and lead a cleaner editing experience.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#variable-reuse

Comment: Do you understand the difference between runtime and compile-time expressions? You're using a variable resolved at runtime (`$[]`) with compilation-time expressions (`${{}}`), which is not going to work, as template compilation happens **before** runtime expressions are evaluated.

Comment: I agree with the comments above. But if you want to do this, I would suggest to use `conditions`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages

Answer (score 0):

After reading @danielmann comment, I looked into the difference between different bracket types.

I had many variables, few were in the template file and others were in an Azure library. I had to refer to the template variables with the compile time brackets $[ ], while the variables saved in the library was enough to refer to them using the normal $() as they are just string replacement. my variables look like this now:

```
variables: 
  - template: myVars.yaml
  - name: registry
    ${{ if eq(myVars.isMaster, 'true') }}:
      value: $[myVars.prod_registry]        # Substituted at compile time
    ${{ else }}:
      value: $[myVars.dev_registry]         # Substituted at compile time
  - name: someKey
    ${{ if eq(myVars.isMaster, 'true') }}:
      value: $(LIBRARY_KEY_PROD)            # Substituted at runtime
    ${{ else }}:
      value: $(LIBRARY_KEY_DEV)             # Substituted at runtime
```

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate felt could be easier to provide an answer of the comment I left;

.....

```
jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      variables:
      ${{ if eq(myVars.isMaster, 'true') }}:
       - template: mainvariables.yml
      ${{ else }}:
       - template nonmainvariables.yml
      steps:
        - template: extras/deploy-thingz.template.yaml
          parameters:
            registry: ${{variables.registry}}
```

variables file structure:

mainvariables.yml

```
variables:
 registry: azurethis.io
```

nonmainvariables.yml

```
variables:
 registry: azurethat.io
```

After it runs you can confirm the variable insertion by going to the individual pipeline, elipses menu, download logs, open azure-pipeline-expanded.yml This will have the fully expanded pipeline. Thus why I switched the syntax from $() to ${{}} we don't need to do this at run time rather makes it easier to track by doing it at expansion. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The problem is that they're mixing runtime and compile-time variable resolution syntax. Your answer does not address that at all.